# Possible to send messages to all the individuals on a event on facebook with a script?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messages

Is it Possible to send messages to all the individuals on a event on facebook with a script?

Say that I am attending a event on facebook, and I want to send a message to all the other people attending individually even those I am not friends with on Facebook. I want to send the same message, but it is a bit of a time stealing thing send the message to everybody one at a time.

Is it possible to make a script or a program that can do that for me?

Comment: If you want to get a good answer, I'd suggest posting what have you tried so far.

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: @Jonathan I am not a programer or anything. I just figured out that this was å good site to ask for help to my little problem. Maybe a challenge for someone...

Comment: As WizKid said, it is impossible.